# How to delete a message from one channel and send to another?

Tags: python, discord.py

How to delete a message from one channel and send to another
I have a code, but the bot does nothing, it just ignores it and there are no errors either

Code -

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if int(message.channel.id) == 1234567890:
        content = message.content 
        await message.delete()
        channel = bot.get_channel(1234567890) 
        await channel.send(content)
```

Comment: I think this is possible. You are use a module `pyperclip` to copy the content to your clipboard and use variables accordingly.

Comment: Double check your IDs of both main channel and target channel. The code seems to have no issues. Try using `print` statements to see if the event and `if` statement even fires.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński *They are not using message ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code should work fine. You just forgot `await bot.process_commands(message)` after the asynchronous definition.
You should also put `await message.delete()` at the end of your function, to be sure that you will always be able to see the message content (this is optional).